# after updating packages, unity launcher is not showing up

Tags: unity

Decided to update my packages using update-manager, now unity launcher isn't working.

If force to launch Unity, this is what I am getting:

```
ilshod@small-camel:~$ unity &
[1] 2440
dilshod@small-camel:~$ unity-panel-service: no process found
dilshod@small-camel:~$ Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.01.upgrade
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.02.upgrade
Initializing core options...done
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
I    nitializing composite options...done
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: No valid GL extensions string found.
Compiz (bailer) - Info: Ensuring a shell for your session
Window manager warning: "" found in configuration database is not a valid value for keybinding "move_to_workspace_4"
Window manager warning: "" found in configuration database is not a valid value for keybinding "move_to_workspace_3"
Window manager warning: "" found in configuration database is not a valid value for keybinding "move_to_workspace_2"
Window manager warning: "" found in configuration database is not a valid value for keybinding "move_to_workspace_1"
Window manager warning: "" found in configuration database is not a valid value for keybinding "toggle_fullscreen"
```

If I run glxinfo, this is what I am getting:

```
dilshod@small-camel:~$ glxinfo 
name of display: :0.0
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  137 (NV-GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  4 ()
  Resource id in failed request:  0x3400003
  Serial number of failed request:  32
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by re-installing Nvidia drivers. For some reason, every time I update core packages I have to reinstall the video drivers. This time for some reason, I was made to believe I didn't have to because Nvidia logo was showing up when launching X.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, rebuilding Nvidia drivers was a must when upgrading Xorg and stuff. Now I don't know the current state of things, but I think they have improved.